# How to import data to a named list?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm able to import data to a list. For example:

```
write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv")
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")
```

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
```

```
imported_files <- list()
for(i in seq_along(files)){
  imported_files[[i]] <- readr::read_csv(file = files[[i]])
}
```

```
names(imported_files)

NULL
```

But the imported_files list has no names.
I'd like to create a list with the names in them. Something like this:

```
names(imported_files)
"iris"
"mtcars"
```

I'm also wondering if it is possible to do this using `lapply` and `purrr::map()`.

Comment: Just replace `imported_files[[i]]` with `imported_files[[files[i]]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `lapply` could be

```r
imported_files <- lapply(files, \(x) readr::read_csv(x))
names(imported_files) <- gsub(".csv", "", files)

names(imported_files)
#> [1] "mtcars" "iris"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind `.csv` in the name, you could also just use `sapply`:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
imported_files <- sapply(files, function(x) readr::read_csv(file = x))
names(imported_files)

[1] "iris.csv"   "mtcars.csv"
```

If you do mind, probably better to use `lapply` with `names` as in the other example, or the below alternative:

```
files <- sub('.csv', '', list.files(pattern="*.csv"))
imported_files <- sapply(files, function(x) readr::read_csv(file = paste0(x, '.csv')))
names(imported_files)

[1] "iris"   "mtcars"
```